# MySQL Query 1054 ERROR

Tags: mysql

```
MySQL Query ERROR
[1054] Unknown column 'Level' in 'field list'
[Query] UPDATE apt_Packages SET
  `Package`='com.myrepospace.i7store.icontool',
  `Name`='icon tool',
  `Version`='1.8-6',
  `Author`='i3tef <ww.ho@hotmail.com>',
  `Section`='هاكات',
  `Level`='0',
  `Price`='',
  `Purchase_Link_Stat`='0',
  `Maintainer`='',
  `Sponsor`='myRepoSpace.com <http://www.myRepoSpace.com>',
  `Depiction`='http://i3tef.com/index.php?pid=2',
  `Description`='ادة لتحكم في الايقونات',
  `Multi`='',
  `Changelog`='',
  `Changelog_Older_Shows`='',
  `Tag`='',
  `Purchase_Link`='commercial.php?action=alipay_go&title=com.myrepospace.i7store.icontool&optEmail=&payAmount='
WHERE `ID`='2'
```

Comment: It's saying that your table doesn't have a column named `Level`.

Comment: You posted and I know that the sunglasses on my head, but the search for a solution

Comment: The error message is clear. If @EdGibbs's comment didn't answer your question for you, you lack the most basic level of knowledge required to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation enough for comment.
That error is saying that MySQL can't find a column named Level for that table. But you need to provide more information so we can help you, an ERR Diagram would be useful.
Maybe you wrote wrong the column name or delete that column in the past.